# Install mysqlclient for Django database via pip

Tags: python, mysql, django

I have installed MySQL-server, python3-dev, libmysqlclient-dev. But whem I try to install mysqlclient via pip, I get some errors that I don't understand. Like this:

```
(Env) randomparatololer@randomparatololer:~/Documents/DJANGO/tigabelas$ pip install mysqlclient
Collecting mysqlclient
  Using cached mysqlclient-1.4.6.tar.gz (85 kB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /home/randomparatololer/Documents/DJANGO/Env/bin/python3.8 -C 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-r_ybnapl/mysqlclient/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-r_ybnapl/mysqlclient/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr (tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace ('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec (compile (code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"')' egg_info &ndash; egg-base /tmp/pip-install-r_ybnapl/mysqlclient/pip-egg-info
     cwd: /tmp/pip-install-r_ybnapl/mysqlclient/
    Complete output (11 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
     File "/home/randomparatololer/Documents/DJANGO/Env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 20, in <module>
     from setuptools.dist import Distribution, Feature
     File "/home/randomparatololer/Documents/DJANGO/Env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 35, in <module>
     from setuptools import windows_support
     File "/home/randomparatololer/Documents/DJANGO/Env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/windows_support.py", line 2, in <module>
     import ctypes
     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/ctypes/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
     from _ctypes import Union, Structure, Array
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_ctypes'
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: Python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: Check the logs for full command output.

Comment: I would bet that this has to do with the `mysqlclient` setup not being able to locate `openssl` (or another dependency).  Can you show full traceback?  The answer is likely there.